# Temperature threshold of a cell

Tags: cell-biology

While human body as a whole will find a increase in temperature by 2 C fatal, what about individual cells? If temperature of a cell or tissue is maintained at higher temperature via external mechanism , say a sophisticated heating rod, how much temperature rise it can take before dieing? Say, endothelial cells lining blood vessels. Or,any other cell.

Comment: different cells and tissues have different tolerances, so you will have to be more specific.

Comment: A core body temperature of 39°C is far from fatal, so you are starting from an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about cells in general, the main problem about higher temperatures is the [denaturation of proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaturation_(biochemistry)) (when proteins lose their structure and then they don't work anymore), and every organism has a specific range of temperatures in which its proteins have evolved to work in that determined range.

The most common example of bacteria living at high temperatures is Thermus aquaticus ([or others](https://www.promega.com/~/media/Files/Resources/Technical%20References/Properties%20of%20Thermostable%20DNA%20Polymerases.pdf)) which proteins are widely used in laboratories for their peculiarity to be able to work at more than 70 °C (e.g. [polymerase chain reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymerase_chain_reaction)).

In humans the mean temperature is 37 °C, and it's not unusual during severe fevers to get it rising to 39-40 °C (so the assumption that over 39 °C occurs death is incorrect). Of course you can reach higher temperatures but reaching 43-44 °C leads to multi-organ damages. You can find out more in [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3609720/).

Another thing to take in consideration is that cells must contain water in liquid phase, so over the 100 °C limit (at atmospheric pressure, so the limit can increase alongside pressure) it's kind of impossible to find living cells.

Comment: The highest I found is 122 °C (http://www.pnas.org/content/105/31/10949) but you have to consider the high pressure that keeps water a liquid and not a gas.

Comment: I think the question was about the temperature tolerance of *human* cells, not extreme thermophile bacteria, so this seems to be veering off topic ...

Comment: Reading the question and the comment wrote by John I thought it was clearer to take them as example, anyway the thermophile-related sentences can be easily deleted.